# What happens if I remove lock() from this implementation of producer/consumer queue by Albahari

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm learning multithreading and have come to a producer/consumer problem.

Here is the [sample implementation of a producer/consumer queue taken from the Albahari's website](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx) (authors of the "C# in a Nutshell" book series):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class ProducerConsumerQueue : IDisposable
{
  EventWaitHandle _wh = new AutoResetEvent (false);
  Thread _worker;
  readonly object _locker = new object();
  Queue<string> _tasks = new Queue<string>();

  public ProducerConsumerQueue()
  {
    _worker = new Thread (Work);
    _worker.Start();
  }

  public void EnqueueTask (string task)
  {
    lock (_locker) // <---------------------------------------------- 1
      _tasks.Enqueue (task);
    _wh.Set();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    EnqueueTask (null);     // Signal the consumer to exit.
    _worker.Join();         // Wait for the consumer's thread to finish.
    _wh.Close();            // Release any OS resources.
  }

  void Work()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      string task = null;
      lock (_locker) // <---------------------------------------------- 2
        if (_tasks.Count > 0)
        {
          task = _tasks.Dequeue();
          if (task == null) return;
        }
      if (task != null)
      {
        Console.WriteLine ("Performing task: " + task);
        Thread.Sleep (1000);  // simulate work...
      }
      else
        _wh.WaitOne();         // No more tasks - wait for a signal
    }
  }
}
```

I understand the code, but my question is what happens if I remove locks in rows commented with "1" and "2"?
I tried to imagine different concurrent scenarios and couldn't have found one which would lead to a problem.

**If you decide to answer my question please show a detailed step-by-step sequence of actions which would lead to a problem.**

Comment: I'm just curious what is wrong with my question that someone has downvoted it?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Queue<T>` is not thread-safe.

If you write to it from multiple threads, it will break.
(probably when two threads try to resize the buffer at once)

Also, even if it was thread-safe, removing the second lock would allow a second thread to remove the last item while a first thread is inside the `if`, making the first thread try to read an empty queue.

Comment: In his last sentence SLaks is talking about the Work() method. But there can be only one thread executing that method on a single object instance.

Comment: So, why do we need the second lock?

Comment: @Junior1993: Because those methods aren't threadsafe, so the queue can still break.

Comment: SLaks, could you please explain in details (step-by-step) how it can break if we remove only the second lock?

Comment: @Junior1993: One thread calls `Enqueue()` while another thread calls `Dequeue()`.  The second thread modifies the old array after the first thread resized the queue into a new array.